# PHP SQL Add words to specific record in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to add 2 different words to a specific field in a table.

table is:

```
field1, field2 and field3
```

So first I need to select the records that I want to alter:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where field3 = 1
```

Suppose the result is 10 records.

I now have 2 variables var1 and var2

I now need to add var1 to 50% of field2 of the table and var2 to the other 50%

How can I do this?

Example:

table:

```
  id | field2 | field3
-----------------------------
  1    hello      1
  2    hello2     1
```

String1
String2

Select * from mytable where field3 = 1

Will return 2 fields...

next...

Insert String1 into 50% of result and String2 into the other 50% of result on field2

Output should be:

```
  id | field2         |  field3
-----------------------------
  1    String1 hello      1
  2    String2 hello2     1
```

Comment: do you want to split field2 value in two variables by 50%?

Comment: Just want to insert the content of var1 to half of the result and var2 the the other half. of field2 ...not replace just add to the field

Comment: confusing criteria.. can you please provide an example data set, and explain the logic how it should update?

Comment: Forms have fields. Tables have rows and columns. Once you've processed that, consider providing proper DDLs and/or and sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT.

Comment: Do you mean you want 5 rows with var1 in field2, and 5 rows with var2 in field 2?

Comment: can you give an example table with a few rows, examples for var1 and var2 and a desired result set, that would be helpful

Comment: See the question Example part...I've explained it further

Comment: save sql result as `$newdata[0]1 = $string1.' '.row[0][field2]` and `$newdata[1] = $string2.' '.row[1][field2]`. Then update table in SQL with $newdata. Now if you have 10 record 1st five in loop $newdata[0] to $newdata[4] will have $string1 and $newdata[5] to $newdata[9] will have $string2. Its all in PHP Loop where you are reading your SQL rows.

Comment: Do you care how date is distributed across rows, other than you want an approximate split?

Comment: I don't mind about how date is distributed, just need 50 50 split where possible

Comment: If you are trying to get records from table by concatenating PHP string into the query then you might need something like `SELECT CONCAT('$string1',field2) AS newField2, COUNT(id) AS total FROM fields Where field3 = 1 AND id <= total/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get count rows for update.

```
select count(*) cnt 
from MyTable 
where field3 = 1;
```

and in php store result to variable $cnt, also make calculation for the  middle point between ranges.

```
$middle = ceil($cnt/2);
```

then run following query (of course don't forget to escape a values for variables passed in sql):

```
update MyTable a,
      (SELECT @rownum:=0) b
set field2 = concat(field2, if((@rownum := @rownum+1) > $middle, '$var1', '$var2'))     
where field3 = 1;
```

Example below:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbtest');
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, "select count(*) cnt from MyTable where field3 = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$cnt = $row['cnt'];
$middle = ceil($cnt/2);
$var1 = 'xxx';
$var2 = 'yyy';
mysqli_query(
    $conn, 
    "update MyTable a,
           (SELECT @rownum:=0) b
     set field2 = concat(field2, if((@rownum := @rownum+1) > $middle, '$var1', '$var2'))     
     where field3 = 1
    "
);
```

Comment: Getting an error: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) cnt FROM mytable where field3=1");

$middle = ceil($cnt/2);  -- Error is: Undefined variable: cnt

Comment: Example has been added to answer.

Comment: Tried your example...Getting no errors but table is unchanged

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if this works for mysql, but i suggest something like this (ms sql server syntax):

```
update mytable
set field2 = case when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)%2 = 0
                  then 'var1' + field2
                  else 'var2' + field2
             end
where field3 = 1
```

or if you do not wish to update your table but only select the values:

```
select field1
     , case when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by 1d)%2 = 0
            then 'var1' + field2
            else 'var2' + field2
       end as field2
     , field3
 where field3 = 1
```

it adds 'var1' to even rows and 'var2' to odd rows. replace 'var1' and 'var2' with your variables.

it works by taking the modulo 2 of each row number and thereby seeing if the row number of the result set is even or odd. it then puts in var1 or var2 depending on the row number being even or odd.